# <HintPath> in *.csproj file doesn't work for VS2012

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012

The following CodedUI Dlls are shipped with VS2012. What I did was just copy them to a separate folder and reference them from there. I checked the *.csproj file, it has the correct  info as below. But in VS2012 property window, I checked the reference path, they are STILL resolved the default locations like "D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v4.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.CodedUITestFramework.dll"

The  works for only one of the following DLLs, the "Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework". But I don't see anything different between how this DLL is referenced and the others.

WTF is this happening?

I see some other guy reported a bug about VS 2012 assembly binding.(http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vsunittest/thread/ba271f86-ed33-49a5-9b52-99980e88d198)

But I am using the RTM version!

```
<Reference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.CodedUITestFramework, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
   <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
   <HintPath>..\..\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.CodedUITestFramework.dll</HintPath>
 </Reference>
 <Reference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
   <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
   <HintPath>..\..\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll</HintPath>
 </Reference>
 <Reference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Common, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
   <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
   <HintPath>..\..\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Common.dll</HintPath>
 </Reference>
 <Reference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
   <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
   <HintPath>..\..\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.dll</HintPath>
 </Reference>
 <Reference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
   <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
   <HintPath>..\..\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.dll</HintPath>
 </Reference>
```

A ticket has been submitted to MS Connect:  https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/758647/hintpath-in-csproj-file-doesnt-work-for-vs2012

Comment: Next time you might only open a bug report on Visual Studio 2012 to Microsoft. I don't think posting here is that meaningful when you are 100% sure it is a bug.

Comment: Actually, I am not 100% sure. I just want to post it here to see if anyone else meet this.

Comment: I am experiencing similar behavior. And I can't wrap my head around it. Prior VS2012 we used Microsoft.SqlService.Types.dll library directly from our ThirdParty directory. Now it got all messed up: one project uses our original DLL and the other falls back to directory that is something like yours. The csproj files have exactly the same "Reference" and "HintPath" elements and yet different DLLs are reported in the Properties tool window and consequent build failures due to mismatched DLL versions in two related projects.